# How to debug a web page ( for example : google.com ) , running on chrome browser for IOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I have a defect that occurs only on Chrome browser installed on Ipad Pro. It doesn't happen in Safari. I am able to debug safari but failed in debugging a webpage running on chrome browser. I have checked the Internet and aware that debug Api's are not available for chrome in IOS hence we can't debug it like safari .

Is it possible to debug a website running on chrome on IOS device?

Comment: Try Charles it enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet.

Comment: I want to actually see the console log ,to find the defect which is causing the UI break and a free solution. Charles is paid one.